# mysql: split string in a column, count, concatenate strings

Tags: mysql, string

I have a column *names* representing name|lastname. I want to split a column by "|", count the number of times names appear in the database and concatenate all last names corresponding to the first name.

```
John|Bosch
John|Canon
Alex|Bosch
Nick|Müller
Alex|Lok
```

I know how to split and to count the number of times first name appears but I do not know how to concatenate the corresponding last names.

```
select count(SUBSTRING_INDEX(names, '|', 1)), SUBSTRING_INDEX(names, '|', 1)
from my_table
group by SUBSTRING_INDEX(names, '|', 1)
```

The result of the query should be:

```
2 John Bosch,Canon
2 Alex Bosch, Lok
1 Nick Müller
```

Comment: Concat with GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: @Mihai, should post that as answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use  group_concat this way

```
select 
    count(SUBSTRING_INDEX(names, '|', 1)) as Num, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(names, '|', 1)  as Main , 
    group_concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(names, '|', -1))  as Grouped
from my_table
group by SUBSTRING_INDEX(names, '|', 1)
```